# How to insert new records to mysql with no key name assigned and with auto increasing primary key?

Tags: mysql

How to insert new records to mysql with no key name assigned and with auto increasing primary key?

refer to [PHP mySQL - Insert new record into table with auto-increment on primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492145/php-mysql-insert-new-record-into-table-with-auto-increment-on-primary-key)
changed th first value to DEFAULT ,but still same error occurs

[image]

table structure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `configuration_copy`;
CREATE TABLE `configuration_copy` (
  `configuration_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `configuration_title` text NOT NULL,
  `configuration_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `configuration_value` text NOT NULL,
  `configuration_description` text NOT NULL,
  `configuration_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `sort_order` int(5) default NULL,
  `last_modified` datetime default NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL default '0001-01-01 00:00:00',
  `use_function` text,
  `set_function` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`configuration_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq_config_key_zen` (`configuration_key`),
  KEY `idx_key_value_zen` (`configuration_key`,`configuration_value`(10)),
  KEY `idx_cfg_grp_id_zen` (`configuration_group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of configuration_copy
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `configuration_copy` VALUES ('1', 'World Points', 'WORD_POINTS', '0', 'Points required upgrading to world grade', '1', '1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2012-12-30 09:38:23', null, null);
INSERT INTO `configuration_copy` VALUES ('2', 'Iron Points', 'IRON_POINTS', '1000', 'Points required upgrading to iron grade', '1', '2', null, '0001-01-01 00:00:00', null, null);
INSERT INTO `configuration_copy` VALUES ('3', 'Bronze Points', 'BRONZE_POINTS', '2000', 'Points required upgrading to bronze grade', '1', '3', null, '0001-01-01 00:00:00', null, null);
INSERT INTO `configuration_copy` VALUES ('4', 'Silver Points', 'SILVER_POINTS', '3000', 'Points required upgrading to silver grade', '1', '4', null, '0001-01-01 00:00:00', null, null);
INSERT INTO `configuration_copy` VALUES ('5', 'Gold Points', 'GOLD_POINTS', '4000', 'Points required upgrading to gold grade', '1', '5', null, '0001-01-01 00:00:00', null, null);
```

Comment: It's pretty clear in the error message. There is an unique constraint on `configuration_key` column and you violated it.

Comment: configuration_key is not a primary key, it can be the same value...

Comment: it cannot: see `UNIQUE KEY unq_config_key_zen (configuration_key)` in your table structure

Comment: thank you,I am clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an unique key `unq_config_key_zen` on the `configuration_key` column, so you cannot insert rows that have the same `configuration_key` value.

```
 UNIQUE KEY `unq_config_key_zen` (`configuration_key`),
```

Comment: no, it is not primary key , the primary key is only configurations_id