# How to insert mysql like this?another field need auto_increment id to split

Tags: mysql

In my database mysql table, there is one field ,It was split by auto_increment id and other str ,  For example:

```
insert into tableName (id, title, link, keyword) values (NULL, 'Title', 'http://www.domain.com/id', 'keyword');
```

How could that work?
http://www.domain.com/id,   this 'id' is the auto_increment id.

Comment: then just leave id,,
insert into tableName (title, link, keyword) values ('Title', 'http://www.domain.com/id', 'keyword');

Comment: You can use the DEFAULT when inserting into a primary key

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mySQL - Insert new record into table with auto-increment on primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492145/php-mysql-insert-new-record-into-table-with-auto-increment-on-primary-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't make it automatically since mysql for auto increment fields, doesn't know beforehand the inserted id. You could update the row after it is inserted:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (title, keyword) VALUES('Title', 'keyword');

UPDATE tableName 
SET link = CONCAT('http://www.domain.com/', LAST_INSERT_ID())
WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

If id is auto_increment you don't need to set it on insert, just like this:

```
insert into tableName (title, link, keyword) values ('Title', 'http://www.domain.com/id', 'keyword');
```

In general if it auto incremented field, it can be your primary key and add other indexes as you need.